# Google Drive shortcut broken after automatic updates

Tags: shortcuts, google-drive, google-drive-file-stream

**The problem is** keeping the shortcut pointing to the correct application executable on startup correctly since the folder path changes with each new version number. Each time this change occurs, it breaks user profile desktop icons for Google Drive.

**The issue occurs** after Google Drive does an automatic update and creates a new sub folder in the main folder of `C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\<36.0.18.0>` related to the correlated build\release number creating this problem.

**Question:** Could I turn off Google Drive automatic updates entirely to resolve, or are there other solutions that might work to resolve this dynamically for the shortcut?

[image]

### Other detail & things I tried...

- Now the `GoogleDriveFS.exe` application is located in `36.0.18.0` so
  the desktop shortcut no longer works as the path made on the install
  points to  `C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File
  Stream\35.0.13.0\GoogleDriveFS.exe` which no longer exists (Directory
  Empty).
- I am aware of the `AutoStartOnLogin` registry entry but this seems to
  be hit and miss for starting every time and even if it did the users
  desktop shortcuts would still not work.
- All google drives were installed with the following parameters
  `GoogleDriveFSSetup --silent --desktop_shortcut`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PowerShell as a **startup script** to identify the newest created `GoogleDriveFS.exe` file from within the `\Drive File Stream` and all beneath sub-folders recursively, and then use its full path to create (or replace) a shortcut `.lnk` file on the public desktop folder, or wherever is most appropriate for you.

Just use *Task Scheduler* or *Group Policy* to run the below logic as a `Computer` **startup script**. If using Task Scheduler, be sure to make the task run under the `SYSTEM` account for security.

#### PowerShell (version 3+)

```
$Src = "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream";
$Lnk = (Get-Childitem -Path $Src -Include "GoogleDriveFS.exe" -File -Recurse | % {"$($_.CreationTime), $($_.FullName)"}) | Sort-Object -Descending | Select -First 1 | %{$_.Split(",")[1].Trim()};
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop" -Name "GoogleDrive.lnk" -Value $Lnk -Force;
```

#### PowerShell (version 2+)

```
$Src = "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream";
$Lnk = (Get-Childitem -Path $Src -Include "GoogleDriveFS.exe" -Recurse | % {"$($_.CreationTime), $($_.FullName)"}) | Sort-Object -Descending | Select -First 1 | %{$_.Split(",")[1].Trim()};
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop" -Name "GoogleDrive.lnk" -Value $Lnk -Force;
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [Sort-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/sort-object.html)
- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)
- [Trim()](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html)
- [New-Item](https://ss64.com/ps/new-item.html)

Comment: That’s worked 

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure in what version it was added, but the install folder at `%programfiles%\Google\Drive File Stream` now contains a `launch.bat` script that can start the latest `GoogleDriveFS.exe`.

You can make a desktop shortcut to `"%programfiles%\Google\Drive File Stream\launch.bat"`, slap the correct icon on it, name it *Google Drive*, and put it on your users' desktops and it *should* always work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier solution for people that do not know about PowerShell or Group Policy.

1. Go to the 'Properties' of the shortcut
2. Replace the version number (eg. 34.0.20.0) with the new version number and save.

   Full file location string:

   ```
    C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\34.0.20.0\GoogleDriveFS.exe
   ```
3. To change the shortcut icon, go to 'Change icon' and navigate to the Google Drive Stream folder and select GoogleDriveFS.exe and it will automatically select the correct icon.

If you change the shortcut properties, you don't need to reinstall